# windows 2008r2 SNMP hrStorageSize reporting wrong values

Tags: windows, snmp

I'm trying to monitor disks on windows 2008 R2 system, but I'm getting wrong values returned from hrStorageSize and hrStorageUsed for one of the 2 disks the system has. Local disk C: is returning correct values, whereas D: disk, which is an SAN disk, is reporting 32G instead of 500G.
Output of `snmpwalk -v 2c -c public hostname-01 .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2 :`

```
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageDescr.1 = STRING: C:\ Label:  Serial Number 7ff87ca6
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageDescr.2 = STRING: D:\ Label:Data  Serial Number dab5b0b9
...
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageAllocationUnits.1 = INTEGER: 4096 Bytes
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageAllocationUnits.2 = INTEGER: 4096 Bytes
...
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageSize.1 = INTEGER: 35834383
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageSize.2 = INTEGER: 7864320
...
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageUsed.1 = INTEGER: 32460169
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrStorageUsed.2 = INTEGER: 3192302
```

I have calculated the first disk (C:) size as 136G, which is correct.
On the other hand, D: is calculated as 30G, where it should be 500G.
I also tried *fsutil* on the system and the output was correct.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The hrStorage stuff behaves strangely a lot more than I'd expect. Try monitoring a volume over 2TB :) I hope you get a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the disk is a data user disk and you have disk quota enabled then check your quota entries.
You should set to "No limit" every entry that belongs to `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` and 
`NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`.

When you enable disk quotas,both entries would get a limit of 30GB. That's why your `D:` drive is calculated as 30GB instead of 500GB.